# Strange CPU Usage History

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cpu-usage, task-manager

My CPU history graph on the task manager is acting strangely.  The fan also seems to be "revving".  Here is an image of what is happening. This is my laptop and the processor is Intel core i5.

[image]

Programs I'm currently running.

- Netbeans
- Firefox
- Chrome

I want to know why this is happening and what is causing this.

Comment: What process is eating up the most cpu cycles during the peaks?

Comment: Probably Netbeans is using the most cycles. @DougWatkins

Comment: But have you checked? I would watch the task manager or similar app to see exactly what is going on during a peak. It may be some background process or something like that.

Comment: Every thing looks normal, nothing special is happening during the spikes. @DougWatkins

Comment: I'll try to restart my laptop and see if the problem resolved

Comment: Are you viewing it for all users or just yourself? Might be a system process.

Comment: I can only view the task manager from my limited profile, I don't have admin priveliges @DougWatkins

Comment: Talk with your admin and see if they can give you rights or help you figure it out. It's possible the sysinternals tools may show you more information. Search for procmon and it might show you what is missed by task manager. Though it might need admin creds also.

Comment: I'll try to contact him @DougWatkins

Comment: ask for admin rights, to capture a xper trace of the CPU usage: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD